# Average area of choosing three points on a surface?

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

Assume I choose three random points on the surface of a sphere. What is the average area? (Each point is independently chosen relative to a uniform distribution on the sphere) Also, what would be the average area if I choose three points on other types of surfaces? Such as 2-dimensional square/circle
 or 1-dimensional line.

Comment: Are you talking about the area of the resulting [spherical triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalTriangle.html), or the triangle created inside of the sphere? And I assume the answer will be vastly different for different surfaces, but symmetry can help and you can ask for a general form in terms of integrals.

Comment: @anon: not inside the sphere, the area of the triangle on the surface (spherical triangle).

Comment: @anon: do you think the ways to exploit the symmetry on these surfaces are similar?

Comment: On the unit sphere, the area is equal to the sum of the angles minus $\pi$. The expected value for one of the angles is $\pi/2$, so the expected value of the area is $3*\pi/2 - \pi = \pi/2$, which is one eigth of the sphere.

Comment: @Willie: Do you mean the angle for the triangle? Why is it equal to the sum of the angles minus $\pi$?. The link from wolfram doesn't say much...

Comment: It is a well-known formula. See http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/AreaOfASphericalTriangle.html

Comment: @Mark: I don't know what other surfaces you have in mind, but probably not because the sphere is a lot more symmetrical than other figures. The circle and square don't make sense because you can't make triangles out of three points without drawing lines outside of them (and they aren't surfaces). You might mean the disk (2-ball) and the square's interior though (in which case this problem is about "triangle picking"; search Mathworld).

Comment: @anon: for a square or circle it be possible to transform them into a three dimensional object with the same surface area?

Comment: @Willie: This may just be a brain fart, but how do you see that the expected value of an angle is $\pi/2$?

Comment: @DJC: It boils down to the fact that, assuming the Earth is spherical, choosing a point on the surface of the earth with uniform distribution implies that the longitude of the point is between $(-180,180)$ with uniform distribution (which you can see by integrating over the latitudes running from $(-90,90)$). Any random choice of $A, B$ fixes the prime meridian and the north pole. The choice of $C$ is independent, so we can use the above considerations.

Comment: @Willie: Cool.  Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An other way to see the result is by a symmetry argument.

For any given spherical triangle, you may toggle each point with their diametrical opposite to obtain a total of $2^3 = 8$ triangles. The key property to see here is that the union of all these triangles is equal to the sphere, and that the intersection of two of these triangles has an area equal to $0$ (it is at most a common side). So they basically form a partition of the sphere (area-wise, at least).

This means that the expected area of a random spherical triangle has to be an eighth that of the total sphere, ie $\pi R^2/2$.

**Edit:**
To clarify the last step, since these $8$ triangles have equal probability, their average area is the sum of the areas ($4\pi R^2$) divided by $8$. Then you need to see that each triangle is part of such a set of $8$ triangles, with no set more probable than any other.

The way I see it: choosing a triangle at random is the same as choosing a set of $8$ triangles (ie, choosing three [great circles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) at random, which relates to the angle solution), and then choosing one of the $8$ triangles uniformly at random.

Comment: "...The key property to see here is that the union of all these triangles is equal to the sphere, and that the intersection of two of these triangles has an area equal to 0 ..." How do I prove this part?

Comment: "...For any given spherical triangle, you may toggle each point with their diametrical opposite to obtain a total of $2^3=8$ triangles..." I still don't feel clear on how to construct these eight triangles. Suppose I just happen to choose all three points at one point. It doesn't seem to work in this case. So, are you talking about the average area or any three points on the surface of a sphere?

Comment: Lastly, suppose the statement is true what would be the procedure to obtain these eight triangles?

Comment: @Mark (1) The sphere's center, along with any pair of the three points, determines a plane.  Use this plane to divide the sphere into two parts.  That gives three planes--one for each point pair--and therefore 2^3 = 8 parts of the sphere are created.  When no two points coincide, each of these parts is nonempty and each part is a triangle.  (2) The chance that two or more of the points coincide equals zero, so you don't have to consider this possibility.

Comment: @whuber: Ok I am convinced that they cover the sphere's surface. But "...This means that the expected area of a random spherical triangle has to be an eighth that of the total sphere, ie $πR^2/2$.." is still not clear to me. How should I prove this part?

Comment: @Mark: by symmetry, the random variable $A$ and the random variable $-A$ have the same distribution, and if $A$ is independent of $B$, we have that $-A$ is also independent of $B$. (The minus sign denote taking the antipode on the sphere.) So the expected area of the triangle $ABC$ is the same as the expected area of teh triangle $(-A)BC$. So using that the areas $ABC + (-A)BC + A(-B)C + \cdots + (-A)(-B)(-C) = 4\pi$, now take the expectation on both sides. The LHS equals 8 times the expectation value of $ABC$, since the area distribution of each of the summands are equal.